# Looking for 4psa_base.h header file to recompile app_fax.c

Tags: c, asterisk, header-files, voip

I am trying to recompile app_fax.c to app_fax.so (module used by asterisk to send/receive fax under 4PSA system) which needs a header file called 4psa_base.h

The reason I am recompiling this c program is because of a timeout setting inside the program that kills fax calls that last more than 30 minute. what I did was just change that value

I have looked everywhere for this file with no luck. its not anywhere that I can find it.

Is there anyone that may have any clue where to find this file?

Thanks,
Javid

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Asterisk you are using, but app_fax (which is not the preferred fax module in Asterisk) depends on [spandsp](http://www.soft-switch.org/). Looking at the [source](http://svn.asterisk.org/svn/asterisk/trunk/apps/app_fax.c), it does not include the header file you're referring to:

```
ASTERISK_FILE_VERSION(__FILE__, "$Revision$")

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <tiffio.h>

#define SPANDSP_EXPOSE_INTERNAL_STRUCTURES
#include <spandsp.h>
#include <spandsp/version.h>

#include "asterisk/lock.h"
#include "asterisk/file.h"
#include "asterisk/logger.h"
#include "asterisk/channel.h"
#include "asterisk/pbx.h"
#include "asterisk/app.h"
#include "asterisk/dsp.h"
#include "asterisk/module.h"
#include "asterisk/stasis.h"
#include "asterisk/stasis_channels.h"
#include "asterisk/format_cache.h"
```

Is this a custom patch to Asterisk?

Comment: This is a product of 4PSA as mentioned. 4PSA has its own fax app that they use. asterisk version is 1.8

Comment: You need to contact 4PSA then. You're asking for someone to point you to what is almost certainly a proprietary addition to an open source project. I suspect that will end up violating someone's licensing at some point.